# WCF endpoint with an invalid URL

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have inherited a couple of large legacy C# code bases that make extensive use of SOAP/WCF to talk to each other and some third party software. I am somewhat new to WCF. I've run across a situation I can't quite explain. The URL pattern being used for the contracts in one of the service classes is definitely invalid (The top level domain it specifies does not exist).

```
[OperationContract(Name = "TestMethod", Action = "http://hard.coded.URL.that.is.definitely.invalid/TestMethod")]
[WebMethod(MessageName = "TestMethod")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
string TestMethod(string x);
```

Is it possible that this could work, or is the explanation simply that it has never been used?

I don't know for sure that this service has actually been used for anything. The commit messages on all revisions of this file (and most other files) are useless. This is in one of the modules that talks to third party software that I don't currently have the ability to deploy in a test environment. There are a lot of other WCF endpoints in the project that use valid URL patterns.

Maybe they were doing something really weird with the DNS configuration(?) This service most likely would be run over a local network.